# What is the limiting factor in /dev/zero speed?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, file

I have installed 4 brand-new SATA hard drives in a mac pro.  My OS is running on a fifth drive (SSD).  I run this command

```
pv /dev/zero -tpreb | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=512k
```

for many hours to stress test the new drives.  Right away it maxes out the drive write speed at 170MBps.  I open a second terminal and run the command on the second drive simultaneously, and they both go around 170MBps.  But as I add the third and fourth drives, the speed drops to 135MBps each.  This makes me believe that the read speed of /dev/zero is the limiting factor, but why?
I have 28GB free memory, and my CPU is hardly being used.

Comment: How many buses are involved?  I'd guess that the limit you've reached is due to the bus.

Comment: That's a good question.  Anyone know how many internal SATA busses are in a 2010 Mac Pro?  Each SATA II bus should be 375MBps, right? But I'm getting a total of ~530MBps.